# How to get current position in OnClick method to remove row

Tags: java, listview

i am totally new to Java and have been stuck for hours now. I have watched so many topics but nothing that I can apply without errors. However I guess this is not something complicated.

I have to create a method OnClick that will delete the entire row, which is made of txtListJour, txtListMontant, txtListMotif and cmdSuppHf. cmdSuppHf is the delete button.

Here is the code : the inline commented part isn't working obviously:

```
class FraisHfAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final ArrayList<FraisHf> lesFrais ; // liste des frais du mois
private final LayoutInflater inflater ;


public FraisHfAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FraisHf> lesFrais) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) ;
    this.lesFrais = lesFrais ;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lesFrais.size() ;
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int index) {
    return lesFrais.get(index) ;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int index) {
    return index;
}


private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtListJour ;
    TextView txtListMontant ;
    TextView txtListMotif ;
    ImageButton cmdSuppHf ;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder ;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder() ;
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_liste, parent, false) ;
        holder.txtListJour = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtListJour);
        holder.txtListMontant = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtListMontant);
        holder.txtListMotif = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtListMotif);
        holder.cmdSuppHf = convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmdSuppHf);
        convertView.setTag(holder) ;
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.txtListJour.setText(String.format(Locale.FRANCE, "%d", lesFrais.get(index).getJour()));
    holder.txtListMontant.setText(String.format(Locale.FRANCE, "%.2f", lesFrais.get(index).getMontant())) ;
    holder.txtListMotif.setText(lesFrais.get(index).getMotif()) ;
    // holder.cmdSuppHf.setOnClickListener(view -> delete(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
    holder.cmdSuppHf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // int index = view.getTag();
            }
    });

    return convertView ;
}



}
```

My question is : how can I take the index (position) to delete the appropriate line ? If you could put me on the track I would be really grateful !

Comment: In OnClick I also tried this :
holder.txtListJour.setVisiblity(View.GONE); however it states that holder has to be declared final. When I declare it final, setVisibility method appears in red (unrecognized)...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing that on your adapter, do this in your activity.
Just implement a clickListener for your ListView

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    listView.removeViewAt(position);
}
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering me but i have an "OnItemClickListener' is abstract ; cannot be instantiated error. Also, is this deleting a row by clicking on it ? I really need to use the delete button unfortunately...